# How do I make Codenameone RSSReader scrolling smooth and less jumpy?

Tags: codenameone

I am using codenameone RSSReader. On the simulator, it is difficult to use as the scrolling is quiet jumpy. if you scroll up, it will scroll and then bounce back to the previous position and it is difficult to select an item that is not within the view window. What do i need to do to make the scrolling smooth and not jumpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the form to border layout and place the reader in the center of the form.